# How to fetch object data from an ifPresentOrElse statement?

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I am trying to fetch some data from and object. I have a small piece of code where:

`UserAccessValidator` is just a validator, the method `validateAccessToAccount` takes an `Long`, and throws and exception when the access is not granted. Simple as that.

```
userAccessValidator.validateAccessToAccount(
    peripheralRepository.findById(peripheralId)
        .ifPresentOrElse(p -> p.getAccount().getId(),
            () -> {throw new NotFoundException(Peripheral.class);}));
```

It doesn't compile, i get an information that `Long` is required but provided is void.

How can I fix this piece of code for it to work? I would like to get the account Id, but I do not know how to achieve this... A more detailed explaination would be very appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifPresentOrElse​()` has a void return type, so it's not suitable to return a value.

Use `map` to map the value inside the `Optional` into the desired account ID. This would return another `Optional`.

Then you can call `orElseThrow`, which would throw the exception if the `Optional` is empty, and return the value stored within that `Optional` if not.

```
userAccessValidator.validateAccessToAccount(
        peripheralRepository.findById(peripheralId)
                            .map(p -> p.getAccount().getId())
                            .orElseThrow​ (() -> {throw new NotFoundException(Peripheral.class);});
```